# Vaadin 22 Starter not working in a standalone instance of Jetty v9

Tags: jetty, vaadin, jetty-9, vaadin22

I have cloned from https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow/tree/v22

I produce a .war file (project-base-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war) in the target directory using,
`mvn package -Pproduction`

I pop the .war into the webapps directory of a standalone instance of Jetty v9.4.46

Using Chrome, I open http://localhost:8080/project-base-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ and all I get is a directory listing.

Doing the same thing with standalone Tomcat (v8.5.78) works as expected.

Running,
`mvn jetty:run`
also works as expected

It doesn't work with Jetty v10.0.9 either

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Jetty logs show is something is wrong with your Jetty but what you do works fine for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow.git
cd skeleton-starter-flow
git checkout v22
mvn package -Pproduction
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.4.46.v20220331/jetty-distribution-9.4.46.v20220331.tar.gz
tar zxvf jetty-distribution-9.4.46.v20220331.tar.gz
cp target/project-base-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war jetty-distribution-9.4.46.v20220331/webapps
cd jetty-distribution-9.4.46.v20220331
bin/jetty.sh run
```

Then http://localhost:8080/project-base-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ shows the application with a text field and a button

Comment: Thank you @artur-signell ... I was using a Jetty Base and followed the instructions [from here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#creating-jetty-base). I see now, that I also needed to do a, `--add-to-start=annotations`

Comment: `jetty-distribution` has been replaced by `jetty-home` and the Jetty project recommends using the `${jetty.base}` instance and `${jetty.home}` install directory split. (Jetty 10+ has no jetty-distribution artifact anymore)